# restart apache every 12 hours using linux service and python file

Tags: python, linux, apache, bash

Hi i want to use this for restart apache service every 12 hours and 
i put the file `apache_rest` in `/etc/init.d/apache_rest`
i run but get some error :

```
[root@localhost init.d]# service apache_rest start
Starting server
/etc/init.d/apache_rest: line 13: /sbin/start-stop-daemon: No such file or directory
```

apache_rest file:

```
#!/bin/bash
WORK_DIR="/var/lib/foo"
DAEMON="/usr/bin/python"
ARGS="/home/lol/apache.py"
PIDFILE="/var/run/foo.pid"
USER="foo"
case "$1" in
  start)
    echo "Starting server"
    mkdir -p "$WORK_DIR"
    /sbin/start-stop-daemon --start --pidfile $PIDFILE \
        --user $USER --group $USER \
        -b --make-pidfile \
        --chuid $USER \
        --exec $DAEMON $ARGS
    ;;
  stop)
    echo "Stopping server"
    /sbin/start-stop-daemon --stop --pidfile $PIDFILE --verbose
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/$USER {start|stop}"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
exit 0
```

and the python file :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os,signal,time,multiprocessing
stop_event = multiprocessing.Event()
def stop(signum, frame):
    stop_event.set()
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, stop)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    while not stop_event.is_set():
        os.system('service httpd restart')
        time.sleep(43200)
```

thanks ^_^

Comment: did you run it under root?

Comment: Problem seems to be that the file `/sbin/start-stop-daemon` doesn't exist. Does it?

Comment: yes you can see it's run by root : [root@localhost init.d]#

Comment: i dont know what is that file ... can you help me ?

Comment: @user2328647 Which Linux distribution are you using (e.g. Debian, Redhat, etc.)?

Answer (score 4):

Simply add this line to root's crontab:

```
0 1,13 * * * /etc/init.d/httpd restart
```

You don't need such a convoluted solution.

Comment: Can you explain more please Mr.Khalid 
I'm new , Thanks

Comment: `i dont want use corn` why do people keep saying `i don't want to use this solution that is designed to do what I am trying to do, I'd rather reinvent the wheel`.